# How to find graph's degeneracy?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

How can I verify if the graph is k-degenerate or not? 
How to find graph's degeneracy?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory)

Comment: This should have been closed as "not research level" rather than "too broad".

Answer (score 7):

The following greedy algorithm determines the degeneracy of a graph $G$ (defined to be the maximum, taken over all subgraphs $H$ of $G$, of the minimum degree of $H$).

Initialise $G_1:=G$ and $n:=|V(G)|$. For $i=1,\ldots,n$, let $d_i$ be the minimum degree of $G_i$, let $v_i$ be a vertex of degree $d_i$ in $G_i$, and let $G_{i+1}:=G_i-v_i$.

Say $d_i$ is maximum among $d_1,\dots,d_n$. I claim that $d_i$ equals the degeneracy of $G$. Since $G_i$ has minimum degree $d_i$, the degeneracy of $G$ is at least $d_i$. Conversely, consider a subgraph $H$ of $G$. Let $v_j$ be the vertex in $H$ with $j$ minimum. Then $d_i$ is at least $d_j$ (by the definition of $d_i$), which equals the degree of $v_j$ in $G_j$, which is at least the degree of $v_j$ in $H$ (since $H$ is a subgraph of $G_j$ by the definition of $v_j$), which is at least the minimum degree of $H$. That is, the minimum degree of $H$ is at most $d_i$. Hence the degeneracy of $G$ is at most $d_i$. Therefore the degeneracy of $G$ equals $d_i$.